# How to append console output to a file in maven?

Tags: maven, logging, exec-maven-plugin

I am using exec-maven-plugin to execute some specific tests. I want to append the console output of the tests to a file, without hiding the console.
Is there any support provided in maven for the task?

1. I used maven-antrun-plugin to execute the recorder task before the tests begin. That didn't work.
2. I used 'tee' command to execute using exec-maven-plugin. That doesn't seem to work either.
3. I checked using log4j with maven. But since i'm new to log4j logging, i couldn't debug the issue with it.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That's a tough one. What happened when you used `tee`?

Comment: I gave the execution of `tee` as one of the `<execution>` and made it to run in background.  But the problem is, I can't redirect the output of the next `<execution>` to `tee`. Here's the code I used.  `<execution> ... <executable>tee result.log</executable></execution><execution>...<executable>java</executable>...</execution>` Since there's no redirection, the result.log is getting created, but it's not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `outputFile` parameter: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#outputFile

> Program standard and error output will be redirected to the file specified by this optional field. If not specified the standard maven logging is used.
>
> Type: java.io.File
>
> Since: 1.1-beta-2
>
> Required: No
>
> Expression: ${exec.outputFile}

Comment: The `outputFile` option will only redirect the output to the specified file. The output will not be visible on console. I dont want to hide the console output.

Comment: Indeed, sorry I missed that part.

Comment: To avoid this post being removed, I've edited it to include the link contents so if the link breaks this won't be useless to future visitors.